# Why can I not get my network adapter to function in 1000mb full in vSphere 5

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I am trying to tune my vSphere 5 and virtualized SAN for performance, but the network adapters for all networks seems to be stuck at 100Mb Full duplex instead of 1000Mb Full duplex. Does this mean that all communications between VM's on the all virtual networks is stuck at 100Mb full duplex, even though many VM's use the vmxnet3 drivers? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Communications between virtual machines on the same vSwitch on the same box will be very fast and will not traverse the physical uplinks unless they are assigned to separate port groups that use an upstream device for inter-vlan routing. If your physical links are showing 100Mb, then your issue is probably the physical switch those NICs are connected to.

Comment: How fast is very fast? The only traffic going to the physical nic at the moment is for the vSphere Client, everything else is interal.

Comment: That's a good question, even though each guest will show that it has a 1Gb link, I think it will go well over 1Gb in throughput internally since the latency won't climb. Perhaps someone else knows how fast it will go.

Comment: If you're using VMXnet 3, you're going to get UP TO 10Gb connectivity from guest to guest, but keep in mind with a single host you're probably going to be constrained by disk I/O before you hit a "networking" limitation, but maybe not if you're using FLASH or SSD storage.